# How can I check if an integer or float number in a list is positive or negative in sign?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, python-3.6, negative-number

I'm using Python 3.6.  What would be an efficient way to check if a float or integer number within a list is negative or positive?

I want to iterate through a list, retrieving only the indexes of numbers of a particular sign.

For example:

```
x = [1,-7, 9, 3, 6, -3 ]

y = [ i for i in x if i    **____**   ]
```

I feel like its right under my nose, but its just not coming to me.

Comment: Why not check whether `i` is greater or less than 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
x = [1,-7, 9, 3, 6, -3 ]

y = [elem for elem in x if elem < 0]

z = [elem for elem in x if elem > 0]

print(y)  # -> [-7, -3]
print(z)  # -> [1, 9, 3, 6]
```

In this somewhat special case, you could use a slightly different approach and create both lists simultaneously:

```
x = [1,-7, 9, 3, 6, -3 ]

yz = y, z = [], []
for elem in x:
    yz[elem > 0].append(elem) if elem else None

print(y)  # -> [-7, -3]
print(z)  # -> [1, 9, 3, 6]
```